# Date Stamp in multiple Columns Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have started using this script to auto populate the date when data is entered into the column next to it for Google Sheets.  It needs to do this on multiple columns as new data is entered. This script works on all of the columns but the last paired:  13-14 and 15-16.  It was working before but now it has stopped.  Any help with what I need to do? I'm not versed in code and I learned this much from YouTube!  Thanks!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col == 5  && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "IRLA Level" ) { 
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,6).setValue(new Date())

  if(col == 7  && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "IRLA Level" ) 
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).setValue(new Date())

  if(col == 9  && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "IRLA Level" )
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,10).setValue(new Date())

  if(col == 11  && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "IRLA Level" )
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).setValue(new Date())

  if(col == 13  && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "IRLA Level" )
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,14).setValue(new Date())

  if(col == 15  && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "IRLA Level" )
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).setValue(new Date())

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try it this way

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const idx = [5,7,9,11,13,15].indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if(sh.getName() == "IRLA Level" && e.range.rowStart > 1 && ~idx) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

[Bitwise Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: The date  works for 5,7,9, but does not enter the date for 11,13,15.

Comment: No  I take that back it worked!  I put it in a different spreadsheet and it worked. Thanks a bunch!